# TableView doesn't not scrolling and cells is not enabled

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, scroll

I've created UIImageView with tableView and put this view on another view. But my table isn't enabled. I can't press on the cell or scroll my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a UIView with your UIImageView and UITableView as subviews. 
I don't think it's a good idea to have your table as a subview of an imageview.
I suppose you did this to have a background image for the table, but a transparent table with an image view behind can easily achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a UITableView as a subview of a UIImageView?
If that is the case then the problem is probably that userInteraction is disabled on your UIImageView (it is set to NO as default for UIImageViews).

You can try to set it to YES and see if you can interact with your UITableView. However I would not recommend this view structure as I don't believe it is intended to put UITableViews as subviews to UIImageViews

Comment: Yes, I have a UITableView as a subview of a UIImageView. UserInteraction is enabled on my UIImageView and set to TRUE. But UITableView is not working. Do you have any idea?